# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-mqa_uywo/grpcio/

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, firewall

While install opensnitch firewall, make command giving error,

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-mqa_uywo/grpcio/
make[1]: *** [Makefile:10: deps] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kikguy/.go/src/github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/ui'
make: *** [Makefile:14: ui/resources_rc.py] Error 2
```

I m following this guide: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/how-to-install-opensnitch-application.html

Comment: what's the exact python version? `python3 --version`

Comment: Python 3.7.5
Python 2.7.17 (just in case)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone runs in to this in the future.

You need to update pip with these commands.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```